# WPF: UserControl pulsing background color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Using .NET 3.5

I have a `UserControl` with a `LinearGradientBrush` for the background.

I'm wondering how can I cause the whole control to change to a different color and pulsate when a property on the user control changes.

For example if I say `MyUserControl.Prop1 = 20` then change the color to red and pulse (by pulsating I mean geting brighter then darker and toggling back and forth). Then when  `MyUserControl.Prop1 = 0` it returns back the original color.

I would preferably like to keep the gradient background when pusating a different color but if this isn't possible then so be it

Any pointers or links would be great. I've googled this but didn't find anything useful.

This is my UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="StatusPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Margin="11" >

<Grid>
    <Border Margin="-5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="30" >
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect />
    </Border.Effect>

    <Border.Background >
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Silver" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    </Border>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- All my user contraols defined here -->
    </StackPanel>    
</Grid>    
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This should be a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Comment: What version of WPF are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't post comments for some reason!

Good answer Greg, thanks for that. Unfortunatly i'm using 3.5 .. forgot to mention that when I first asked the Q

this is what I did to solve it:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard Name="FadeOutStoryboard" x:Key="FadeOutStoryboard" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="userControlStatusPanel" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                         From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever"  />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

        Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)UserControl.FindResource("FadeOutStoryboard");
        LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        myBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        myBrush.StartPoint = new Point(1, 1);

        if (runProgress.Percent == 100)
        {
            myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0));
            myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Silver, 1));
            sb.Stop();
        }
        else (runProgress.Percent <= 100)
        {
            myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0));
            myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Silver, 1));
            sb.Begin();
        }
        UserControl.borderMain.Background = myBrush;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unusual to do this sort of thing based on Prop1.  More typically, you'd do it on a visual state like Hover or Focused.

The answer to this question also depends on the version of WPF that you're using.  You don't specify. If you're using at least .Net 4.0, I recommend taking advantage of the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx).  This works in user controls as well as control templates, it just requires a tad more manual work.  :)  For example:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="WpfUserControlTestLibrary.Pulse"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup Name="Prop1State">

            <VisualState Name="Default">
                <Storyboard />
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Error">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        To="Pink" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Stop1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                        Duration="0:0:2" />
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        To="Maroon" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Stop2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                        Duration="0:0:2" />
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        To="Red" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Stop1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                        BeginTime="0:0:2" Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        To="Blue" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Stop2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                        BeginTime="0:0:2" Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="30" Margin="-5">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Border.Effect>

        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0 0" StartPoint="1 1">
                <GradientStop x:Name="Stop1" Color="White" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Color="Silver" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15">
            <Button Content="Default" Click="Button_Click_1" />
            <Button Content="Error" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

With the following code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "Error", false);
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "Default", false);
}
```